# Подставить в abstract свойство свой get

Tags: c#, наследование, методы

Можно ли для вот такого абстрактного класса

```
abstract class Quantity {
    abstract double Value { get; }
}
```

создать наследник, к примеру

```
class Length : Quantity
```

и передать в конструкторе для свойства Value какой-то Метод() без параметров, который возвращает double?

Comment: я попробовал передать ref Func<double> getValue, но его нельзя присвоить свойству Value

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class Quantity {
  public abstract double Value { get; }
}

class Length : Quantity {
  Func<double> metod;
  Length(Func<double> metod) {
    this.metod = metod;
  }
  public override double Value { get { return metod(); } }
}
```

Comment: А, я скобки после делегата забыл